# iPython Notebook, Static Interact; What am I missing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Recently I found [this post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/) on Interactive Widgets.

I am trying to implement this in some simple code, which iterates the logistic equation, and plots the consequent timeseries:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from IPython.html.widgets import interact

plt.close('all')

def logiter(r, x0, t):
    y = []
    x = x0
    for i in range(t):
        x = r*x*(1-x)
        y.append(x)

    fig, plt.plot(y)
    return fig
```

Then import the relevant packages:

```
from ipywidgets import StaticInteract, RangeWidget, RadioWidget

StaticInteract(logiter,
               r=RadioWidget([1, 2, 4]),
               t=RangeWidget(1, 10, 1),
               x0=RadioWidget([0.1, 0.3, 0.7]))
```

But, Alas, the output is a mess. It seems to be plotting all possible combinations of r,t and x0 instead of just one.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

best,
T

Comment: one thing your code is missing: from ipywidgets import StaticInteract, RangeWidget, RadioWidget

Comment: I have changed the example to something a lot easier.

Comment: it looks like your problem is pylab, it is not recommended way

Comment: Um. I don't really get what the problem is? This guy [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/) has lots of working examples. I am struggling to understand the fundamental difference?

Comment: I added working example below, return fig is what was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from IPython.html.widgets import interact

#plt.close('all')

def logiter(r, x0, t):
    y = []
    x = x0
    fig=plt.figure()
    for i in range(t):
        x = r*x*(1-x)
        y.append(x)

    plt.plot(y)
    return fig
from ipywidgets import StaticInteract, RangeWidget, RadioWidget

StaticInteract(logiter,
               r=RadioWidget([1, 2, 4]),
               t=RangeWidget(1, 10, 1),
               x0=RadioWidget([0.1, 0.3, 0.7]))
```

Comment: Great! I knew i had missed something simple.

Comment: before you were plotting every time to the same plot, plt.figure() fixes this

Comment: `ipywidgets.__version__==1.4.0` no longer has StaticInteract,  RangeWigdet, and RadioWidget.  The replacement ipywidgets.IntSlider() and ipywidgets.RadioButton() don't appear to map well.

Comment: This is different ipywidget, search for static ipywidget