# ipywidgets StaticInteract plots all images combination

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-interactive

I am using iPython notebook to test interactive functionalities. The following example (from [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Index.ipynb)) worked fine for me several months ago. However, if I run it now, it plots all the images from possible combinations. I am not sure if this is a duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098281/ipython-notebook-static-interact-what-am-i-missing) didn't help.

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# mpl.rcParams['figure.max_open_warning'] = 1

def plot(amplitude, color):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3),
                           subplot_kw={'axisbg':'#EEEEEE',
                                       'axisbelow':True})

    ax.grid(color='w', linewidth=2, linestyle='solid')
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
    ax.plot(x, amplitude * np.sin(x), color=color,
            lw=5, alpha=0.4)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

    return fig

from ipywidgets import StaticInteract, RangeWidget, RadioWidget

StaticInteract(plot,
               amplitude=RangeWidget(0.1, 1.0, 0.1),
               color=RadioWidget(['blue', 'green', 'red']))
```

This is the output:
[image: output]
Can you help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you can approach it.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider, RadioButtons

amplitude_slider = FloatSlider(min=0.1, max=1.0, step=0.1, value=0.2)
color_buttons = RadioButtons(options=['blue', 'green', 'red'])
# decorate the plot function with an environment from the UIs:
@interact(amplitude=amplitude_slider, color=color_buttons)
def plot(amplitude, color):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3),
                       subplot_kw={'axisbg':'#EEEEEE',
                                   'axisbelow':True})

    ax.grid(color='w', linewidth=2, linestyle='solid')
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
    ax.plot(x, amplitude * np.sin(x), color=color,
        lw=5, alpha=0.4)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
```

Comment: It looks like you gained a +1. I was working with older versions.

Comment: I tried both with ipywidgets 6.0 and this is still a problem for me.